# linq to sql Object Reference not set to an object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this query in Linq to Sql

```
decimal Rewards = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FFUserID == UserID).TotalCommission;
```

This query didn't find a record matching the userID , so obviously that's why the exception is being thrown.  My question is - I thought that by using `.FirstOrDefault()` if there is no record it will return a Default Object - also thought that this default object will have a default value of `0.0M` for `TotalCommission`  .  If that is not how it works then would would be the best way to write this , wanting it to be set to `0.0M` for default.

is this the best?

```
decimal Rewards = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FFUserID == UserID)
                         .TotalCommission ?? 0.0M
```

Comment: just use var rewards as result object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) will return null when no item is found. So when you access the `TotalCommission` property, there's a chance of a `NullReferenceException`. I think you want to do this:

```
decimal Rewards = db.User.Where(x => x.FFUserID == UserID)
                         .Select(x => x.TotalCommission)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
decimal Rewards =
    (from x in db.User
     where x.FFUserID == UserID
     select x.TotalCommission)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**UPDATE:** As of C# 6.0, you can now use the [null-conditional operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) to do something very similar to what you originally intended:

```
decimal Rewards = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FFUserID == UserID)
                        ?.TotalCommission ?? 0.0M
```

The `?.` here will safely handle cases where given user ID is not found in the database and return a `(decimal?)null`. The plain old [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), `?? 0.0M`, will give you the default value you expect.

Comment: ?? can not be applied to type decimal and decimal, since TotalCommission is not nullable , i think the terany operator is getting confused

Comment: @ScottSelby Ahh, I thought `TotalCommision`, was a `decimal?`. See my updated answer. BTW, `??` is not the ternary operator, it's the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal Rewards = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FFUserID == UserID)
                         .TotalCommission ?? 0.0M
```

here in this case you are sure about the TotalCommission will return value. but what about the object which is returned by the FirstOrDefault() you must care about that first then for the rest.

while you a using **firstOrDefault** there are chances that the result could be null. so we must check the nullable before access any property of typed object. otherwise you will surly Get **NulllRefranceExcelption**

so you must be care to check with null reference

alternatively you can do like this.

```
var result = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FFUserID == UserID);


if(result !=null)
{
 var mydata = result.TotalCommission;
}
```

here is the implemantation of **FirstOrDefault** Extension Method

```
     public static TSource FirstOrDefault</tsource,><tsource>(this IEnumerable</tsource><tsource> source) {
         ........
.........
                return default(TSource);
            }
```

So here you can see the result is default(TSource)  which means if the TSource is refrance type this will return null or if the TSource is value type then this will return the default value of TSource. here are some sample implemantation of Default keyword.

```
 Console.WriteLine(default(Int32)); // Prints "0"
        Console.WriteLine(default(Boolean)); // Prints "False"
        Console.WriteLine(default(String)); // Prints nothing (because it is null)
```

Comment: I'm not too sure about that , I think that using FirstOrDefault() will make it so that result is not null , but result.TotalCommission is null

Comment: that's why @p.s.w.g 's answer worked , its only selecting one property - which is a decimal and FirstOrDefault() on that is returning the default value , not null